# How to find the date of last restoration (Windows 7)?

Tags: windows-7, system-restore, windows-7-restore

I am currently working on a old Windows 7 machine.

During a long time (~2 years) the owner did not realise that the backup disk on which Windows was making automatic backups was full. I have deleted some old backups and launched a new backup.

After the backup completed, a warning message appeared in the Maintenance Center saying that **Windows Backup has detected that the computer was restored to a previous restore point and thus it could be that the backup parameters became outdated**.

I am now wondering when that restoration happened and so I am wondering where/how to find this information.

Is there a log file somewhere dedicated to storing such information? Also I tried to look in the Event Viewer module and searched for "restore" or "restoration"... but apparently I am not savvy enough with this tool to efficiently search because up to now I am unable find anything related to restorations...

Comment: Any log likely was already automatically purged due to age. Check the recorded windows events you might be lucky.

Comment: No chance after this length of time. No way to know what happened.

Comment: @Ramhound I am not sure I understand what you mean. How can I "check" the "recorded windows events"?

Comment: Within Event Viewer

Comment: @Ramhound Ah. Well, I did try to look in the Event Viewer but as I explained in my question I am not familiar enough with the tool and I feel a bit overwhelmed by its interface and I don't see clearly how one can search though all the database at once for a keyword such as "restore" or "restoration". Is such a throughout search even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time that Windows restores a System Restore point,
it also creates a new restore point so one can undo the
restore action.

Assuming that no Restore Point was created after the
restore operation you're looking for,
then its date is just the date of the last created
System Restore point.

This is how to get to it on Windows 10. It should be similar on
Windows 7.

- Run *Control Panel > System*
- Select "System protection"
- Click the button "System Restore".

You will see a list of the last created Restore points.

You may lengthen the list to show all Restore point on the
computer by clicking "Show more restore points".
If the allocated disk-space for Restore points is too limited,
the list may be a bit short.

---

You may query in the Event Viewer for all events whose source
is System Restore this way :

- Run the Event Viewer
- Click in the right : Create Custom View...
- Click next to : By source
- Click the drop-down box and select System Restore
- Click anywhere in the dialog to close the drop-down box
- Click in the field showing `<All Event IDs>` and enter 8194,
  which is the event for "Successfully created system restore"
- Click OK
- Enter a name for the view and click OK.

This will create a view with that name that shows all
restore points creations.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, the earliest restore points are just a few days old (there are older ones but for sure they come from backup images on the backup disk). However, in the Event Viewer, for example under Windows Logs/Microsoft/Windows/Backup/Operational, there are events logged that date from more than 10 years. Isn't there any such entry that logs system restoration events?

Comment: Yes, querying for all restore points creations is possible. Added to my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Event ID 8194 corresponds to successful creation of restore points, but I am looking for successful restoration events. But I get it that restore points are created along with restoration events. However, your answer pointed me to these other posts where they mention ID 8202 https://superuser.com/questions/1511451/on-windows-can-i-check-if-a-system-restore-was-executed and https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/138887-how-do-i-check-for-windows-system-resore-success. However I could not find any such entry, so I guess the information is gone with the restore point.

Comment: I haven't found any documentation about event 8202 being related to system restore. I actually haven't found any documentation at all about any event being related to system restore, except the creation of a new restore point or its failure. I suggest perhaps to look for anomalous creation events : wrong time of the day, two in the same day etc.

Comment: Nothing anomalous found. Well, I guess that's it. Thank you.